# Three.js shadows - how to improve?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I've been playing with three.js here - [2toria.com/pool](http://2toria.com)

The issue I'm having is trying to get my shadows to look better.  At the moment, they look like this:-

[image]

A bit pixellated.  Is there a way I can make them look smoother, like here:-

[image]

I've tried a few things, but I can't find the right settings.  My renderer is set up like this:-

```
renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;   
renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;
renderer.shadowMapType = THREE.PCFShadowMap;
```

I thought shadowMapSoft would have done it, but no.  Any ideas/help?

Answer (score 10):

Indeed, I've had the same problem. My fix was to increase my light sources shadowMapWidth and Height. In my case it was a spotLight:

```
spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xAAAAAA );
spotLight.castShadow = true;
spotLight.shadowCameraFov = VIEW_ANGLE;
spotLight.shadowBias = 0.0001;
spotLight.shadowDarkness = 0.2;
spotLight.shadowMapWidth = 2048;
spotLight.shadowMapHeight = 2048;
```

Oh one more thing, if you increase the map size by power's of two you smooth out the shadow's more and more, but you will see a performance hit with complex geometry. So try 2048, maybe 4096 see how they work for ya.

I noticed you have `renderer.shadowMapType`. I'm gonna have to look into that, may make my own projects that much better, thanks :)

Comment: This answer is from 2013 so is likely to be based on r55 - r64.  Do you happen to know the way to soften a shadow in r87?